# Annotating in ggplots with POSIXct class data

Tags: r, ggplot2, time, posixct, annotate

I'm looking for help annotating or creating a legend for 2 subsets of data from the same df on a geom-line plot. The difficulties appear to be because I have POSIXct data on my X-axis. I found a question about the same issue but no clear answer and possibly a bug yet to be addressed - [How to use ggplot2's annotate with dates in x-axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18796386/how-to-use-ggplot2s-annotate-with-dates-in-x-axis)

My plot summarises the median time spent by patients (`left.true`) in an hospital ward across according to the time of arrival onto the ward using data collected over several weeks. The time spent differs according to time of arrival (`start.time`) and the area of the ward they arrive into (`INITIAL.AREA`) so needs to be visualised as two separate lines but plotted together across time for client understanding - hence two geom_line subsets.

Apologies for the inelegant code, but creating the plot crequires time of arrival from one of 2 vectors with a preference for the variable `Add.Time` unless it is not recorded (i.e., `NA`), at which point it sets `start.time` according to an alternative variable.

```
los.plot <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = los2 %>%
              filter(INITIAL.AREA == "AMU") %>%
              mutate(start.time = case_when(
                !is.na(Adm.Time) ~ Adm.Time,
                is.na(Adm.Time) ~ Ward.Start.Time..in.Bed.)) %>%
              select(start.time, left.true) %>%
              group_by(start.time) %>%
              summarise(median = median(left.true)),
            aes(x=start.time, y=(median/60)), color = 'grey30') +
  geom_line(data = los2 %>%
              filter(INITIAL.AREA == "AAA") %>%
              mutate(start.time = case_when(
                !is.na(Adm.Time) ~ Adm.Time,
                is.na(Adm.Time) ~ Ward.Start.Time..in.Bed.)) %>%
              select(start.time, left.true) %>%
              group_by(start.time) %>%
              summarise(median = median(left.true)),
            aes(x=start.time, y=(median / 60)), color='magenta') +
  labs(title = "Median LoS according to initial area of care",
       subtitle = "(Data from October 2019: n=1409)", #NAs removed
       caption = c("AEC patients","AMU Bedded patients"),
       x = "Time of arrival onto unit", 
       y = "Median LoS (hours)") +
  theme(plot.caption = element_text(face = "bold", 
                                    color = c('magenta', 'grey30'),
                                    hjust=c(1, 0))) +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = time.breaks, 
                   labels = c("00:00", "02:00", "04:00", "06:00", '08:00', 
                              '10:00', '12:00','14:00', '16:00', 
                              '18:00', '20:00', '22:00', '24:00'))
```

Trying to use annotate with

```
los.plot + annotate("text", x =03:00:00, y=1, label = "AEC patients",color = 'magenta')
```

leads to

> Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only

I'm assuming this is because the x-axis position argument is incompatible with a POSIXct class. I can't seem to find a way around this.

So far my only solution has been `labs(captions = c(...,...)` as a vector as shown in the main code but it's not an easy plot to understand without a clear legend or labels next to the lines as you can see from the image. I've struggled trying to create a legend from scratch as I have two different subsets of data - however, if anyone has a solution to *this* it would avoid all the POSIX/x-axis dilemma.

[image]

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thank Ronak. I used the whole thing because I wanted to show the plot and though it helped explain it. Since I've been looking for better examples to use, I've stumbled upon where I was going wrong in trying to create my own legend... I should have put the line colours into the aes() call and used scale_fill_manual. Will post as my own answer

Answer (score 1):

Still not further forward with the annotation and time data but I did find out where I was going wrong in creating my own legend - found this post after much searching: [How to add a color legend to a ggplot with different geom layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64413849/how-to-add-a-color-legend-to-a-ggplot-with-different-geom-layers)

This explained that to add a legend I needed to put my color into the `aes()` argument of `geom_line()` and set the colors using scale_fill_manual.

```
los.plot <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = los2 %>%
              ... (as above)
            aes(x=start.time, y=(median/60), color = "AMU Bedded")) +
  geom_line(data = los2 %>%
             ... (as above)
            aes(x=start.time, y=(median / 60), color="AEC")) +
  labs(title = ... (as above)) +
  scale_colour_manual(breaks = c("AMU Bedded", "AEC"),
                      values = c("grey30","magenta"))
```

I had been setting the color *outside* of the `aes()` argument

This now gives:
[image]

Which is exactly what I wanted